# How a Session variable set in Server be accessed in External javascript file?

Tags: javascript, java, session, jstl

```
var xData = ${_attrValues};
```

So I tried using "${}" in external js file but it throws this error ->

[image]

Comment: try enclosing in double quotes: var xData = "${attrValues}";